# Adding Routines MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, events, mysql-workbench, routines

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2.4 and I am trying to create a routine. However, I have no option to create a routine. I've seen the folder come up in the object viewer on other people's application, but it doesn't on mine. I've updated to the latest version of Workbench and that didn't help either. I have the event scheduler on. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: they are described as routines while modeling/diagraming, and as stored procedures/functions in the object browser.

Comment: In fact MySQL Workbench always refers to Stored Functions, Stored Procedures and UDFs as **Routines**.

Comment: @OP: can you add a screenshot showing the place where you expect to see routines? Also what routine do you want to create and where (modeling, SQL IDE)?